# How to use permission_required decorators on django class-based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the new CBVs work. My question is this, I need to require login in all the views, and in some of them, specific permissions. In function-based views I do that with @permission_required() and the login_required attribute in the view, but I don't know how to do this on the new views. Is there some section in the django docs explaining this? I didn't found anything. What is wrong in my code?

I tried to use the @method_decorator but it replies "**TypeError at /spaces/prueba/ _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)**"

Here is the code (GPL):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required

class ViewSpaceIndex(DetailView):

    """
    Show the index page of a space. Get various extra contexts to get the
    information for that space.

    The get_object method searches in the user 'spaces' field if the current
    space is allowed, if not, he is redirected to a 'nor allowed' page. 
    """
    context_object_name = 'get_place'
    template_name = 'spaces/space_index.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get_object(self):
        space_name = self.kwargs['space_name']

        for i in self.request.user.profile.spaces.all():
            if i.url == space_name:
                return get_object_or_404(Space, url = space_name)

        self.template_name = 'not_allowed.html'
        return get_object_or_404(Space, url = space_name)

    # Get extra context data
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewSpaceIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        place = get_object_or_404(Space, url=self.kwargs['space_name'])
        context['entities'] = Entity.objects.filter(space=place.id)
        context['documents'] = Document.objects.filter(space=place.id)
        context['proposals'] = Proposal.objects.filter(space=place.id).order_by('-pub_date')
        context['publication'] = Post.objects.filter(post_space=place.id).order_by('-post_pubdate')
        return context
```

Answer (score 258, accepted):

There are a few strategies listed in [the CBV docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views):

#### Decorate the view when you instantiate it in your `urls.py` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf))

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('view/',login_required(ViewSpaceIndex.as_view(..)),
    ...
]
```

The decorator is applied on a per-instance basis, so you can add it or remove it in different `urls.py` routes as needed.

#### Decorate your class so every instance of your view is wrapped ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class))

There's two ways to do this:

1. Apply `method_decorator` to your CBV dispatch method e.g.,

   ```
    from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    @method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
    class ViewSpaceIndex(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'secret.html'
   ```

If you're using Django < 1.9 (which you shouldn't, it's no longer supported) you can't use `method_decorator` on the class, so you have to override the `dispatch` method manually:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    class ViewSpaceIndex(TemplateView):

        @method_decorator(login_required)
        def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(ViewSpaceIndex, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

2. Use a mixin like [django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) outlined well in the other answers here:

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

    class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

        login_url = '/login/'
        redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
   ```

Make sure you place the mixin class first in the inheritance list (so Python's [Method Resolution Order algorithm](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) picks the Right Thing).

The reason you're getting a `TypeError` is explained in the docs:

> Note:
> method_decorator passes *args and **kwargs as parameters to the decorated method on the class. If your method does not accept a compatible set of parameters it will raise a TypeError exception.

Comment: Mentioned here in latest docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: how to append `message` to it?

Comment: For those who didn't understand (like I did, at first) - the 'dispatch' method should be added to the ViewSpaceIndex class

Comment: Is there any reason to favour one of these methods over the other?

Comment: @Alistair I think it boils down to personal preference and maintaining codebase consistency within your team / organization. I personally tend towards the mixin approach if I'm building class based views though.

Answer (score 120):

Here is my approach, I create a mixin that is protected (this is kept in my mixin library):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Whenever you want a view to be protected you just add the appropriate mixin:

```
class SomeProtectedViewView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

**Just make sure that your mixin is first.**

**Update:** I posted this in way back in 2011, starting with version 1.9 Django now includes this and other useful mixins (AccessMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin) as standard!

Comment: is it possible to have multiple of this kind of mixins? It didn't work for me and I do not think it makes sense it would have.

Comment: Yes it should be possible to have several mixins since each mixin does a call to super that picks the next class in accordance with the MRO

Comment: I think that this is an elegant solution; I don't like having a mixture of decorators in my urls.py and mixins in views.py. This is a way to wrap decorators that would move all of that logic to the view.

Comment: django-braces has this (and more) mixins - a very useful package to install

Comment: Just a note for people in full retard mode like me: make sure that you are not logged in when testing login_required functionality...

Comment: As per your update, here's the link to the docs for AccessMixin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin

Answer (score 51):

Here's an alternative using class based decorators:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

def class_view_decorator(function_decorator):
    """Convert a function based decorator into a class based decorator usable
    on class based Views.

    Can't subclass the `View` as it breaks inheritance (super in particular),
    so we monkey-patch instead.
    """

    def simple_decorator(View):
        View.dispatch = method_decorator(function_decorator)(View.dispatch)
        return View

    return simple_decorator
```

This can then be used simply like this:

```
@class_view_decorator(login_required)
class MyView(View):
    # this view now decorated
```

Comment: You can use this to chain view decorators, nicely! +1

Comment: This is so great it should be considered for inclusion upstream IMO.

Comment: I love this! Im wondering is it at all possible to pass args/kwargs down from the class_view_decorator to the function_decorator???  It would be great if the login_decorator could say conditionally match request.METHOD so it only applies for say post?

Comment: The args/kwargs should be easily achievable by using `class_view_decorator(my_decorator(*args, **kwargs))`. As for conditional method matching - you could modify the class_view_decorator to apply itself to `View.get` or `View.post` instead of `View.dispatch`.

Answer (score 24):

For those of you who use **Django >= 1.9**, it's already included in `django.contrib.auth.mixins` as [`AccessMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin), [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin), [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin) and [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin).

So to apply LoginRequired to CBV(e.g. `DetailView`):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class ViewSpaceIndex(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Space
    template_name = 'spaces/space_index.html'
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

It's also good to keep in mind GCBV Mixin order: *Mixins* must go on the **left** side, and the *base view* class must go in the **right** side. If the order is different you can get broken and unpredictable results.

Comment: This is the best answer in 2019. Also, great point about mixin order.

Answer (score 14):

I realise this thread is a bit dated, but here's my two cents anyway.

with the following code:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from inspect import isfunction

class _cbv_decorate(object):
    def __init__(self, dec):
        self.dec = method_decorator(dec)

    def __call__(self, obj):
        obj.dispatch = self.dec(obj.dispatch)
        return obj

def patch_view_decorator(dec):
    def _conditional(view):
        if isfunction(view):
            return dec(view)

        return _cbv_decorate(dec)(view)

    return _conditional
```

we now have a way to patch a decorator, so it will become multifunctional. This effectively means that when applied to a regular view decorator, like so:

```
login_required = patch_view_decorator(login_required)
```

this decorator will still work when used the way it was originally intended:

```
@login_required
def foo(request):
    return HttpResponse('bar')
```

but will also work properly when used like so:

```
@login_required
class FooView(DetailView):
    model = Foo
```

This seems to work fine in several cases i've recently come across, including this real-world example:

```
@patch_view_decorator
def ajax_view(view):
    def _inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Http404

    return _inner
```

The ajax_view function is written to modify a (function based) view, so that it raises a 404 error whenever this view is visited by a non ajax call. By simply applying the patch function as a decorator, this decorator is all set to work in class based views as well

Answer (score 5):

Use Django Braces. It provides a lot of useful mixins that is easily available. 
It has beautiful docs. Try it out.

You can even create your custom mixins.

http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/

Example Code:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class SomeSecretView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "path/to/template.html"

    #optional
    login_url = "/signup/"
    redirect_field_name = "hollaback"
    raise_exception = True

    def get(self, request):
        return self.render_to_response({})
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a site where the majority of pages requires the user to be logged in, you can use a  middleware to force login on all views *except* some who are especially marked.

Pre Django 1.10 middleware.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf import settings

EXEMPT_URL_PREFIXES = getattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URL_PREFIXES', ())

class LoginRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        path = request.path
        for exempt_url_prefix in EXEMPT_URL_PREFIXES:
            if path.startswith(exempt_url_prefix):
                return None
        is_login_required = getattr(view_func, 'login_required', True)
        if not is_login_required:
            return None
        return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

views.py:

```
def public(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
public.login_required = False

class PublicView(View):
    ...
public_view = PublicView.as_view()
public_view.login_required = False
```

Third-party views you don't want to wrap can be made excempt in the settings:

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URL_PREFIXES = ('/login/', '/reset_password/')
```

Answer (score 4):

In my code I have written this adapter to adapt member functions  to a non-member function:

```
from functools import wraps


def method_decorator_adaptor(adapt_to, *decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs):
    def decorator_outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
            @adapt_to(*decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs)
            def adaptor(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return adaptor(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorator
    return decorator_outer
```

You can simply use it like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from some.where import method_decorator_adaptor


class MyView(View):
    @method_decorator_adaptor(permission_required, 'someapp.somepermission')
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Comment: It would be nice that this was a built-in on Django (just like `method_decorator` is). It seems a nice and readable way of achieving this.

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while now and now Django has changed so much.

Check here for how to decorate a class-based view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

The documentation did not include an example of "decorators that takes any argument". But decorators that take arguments are like this:

```
def mydec(arg1):
    def decorator(func):
         def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
             return func(*args, **kwargs) + arg1
         return decorated
    return deocrator
```

so if we are to use mydec as a "normal" decorator without arguments, we can do this:

```
mydecorator = mydec(10)

@mydecorator
def myfunc():
    return 5
```

So similarly, to use `permission_required` with `method_decorator`

we can do:

```
@method_decorator(permission_required("polls.can_vote"), name="dispatch")
class MyView:
    def get(self, request):
        # ...
```

Comment: I think it is the easiest way to achieve permissions in class base views by checking other permissions that the classic `@login_required`... Also you can pass more than one custom permission as the following `@permission_required(['polls.can_vote', 'polls.change_vote'])` .

Answer (score 1):

I've made that fix based on Josh's solution

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sample usage:

```
class EventsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    template_name = "events/list_events.html"
    model = Event
```

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy with django > 1.9 coming with support for `PermissionRequiredMixin` and `LoginRequiredMixin`

Just import from the auth

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class YourListView(LoginRequiredMixin, Views):
    pass
```

For more details read [Authorization in django](https://medium.com/@amarsavalagi/authorization-in-django-webapp-cbd0b6ea18ce)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a project which requires variety of permission tests, you can inherit this class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator



class UserPassesTest(View):

    '''
    Abstract base class for all views which require permission check.
    '''


    requires_login = True
    requires_superuser = False
    login_url = '/login/'

    permission_checker = None
    # Pass your custom decorator to the 'permission_checker'
    # If you have a custom permission test


    @method_decorator(self.get_permission())
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserPassesTest, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_permission(self):

        '''
        Returns the decorator for permission check
        '''

        if self.permission_checker:
            return self.permission_checker

        if requires_superuser and not self.requires_login:
            raise RuntimeError((
                'You have assigned requires_login as False'
                'and requires_superuser as True.'
                "  Don't do that!"
            ))

        elif requires_login and not requires_superuser:
            return login_required(login_url=self.login_url)

        elif requires_superuser:
            return user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_superuser,
                                    login_url=self.login_url)

        else:
            return user_passes_test(lambda u:True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for permission_required decorator:

```
class CustomerDetailView(generics.GenericAPIView):

@method_decorator(permission_required('app_name.permission_codename', raise_exception=True))
    def post(self, request):
        # code...
        return True
```