# Accessing user in Class-based generic views

Tags: django, firefox, django-generic-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to check if `user.is_authenticated()` or if `user.has_perm()` but it seems impossible extending django Class-based genering views. The only method I found where the `request` appears is `get()`.

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

there I found that `request.user` is instance of `AnonymusClass` no matter if I'm logged in or not.

```
(Pdb) request.user.__class__
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser'>
```

so checking for authentification or perms will always fail:

```
(Pdb) self.request.user.is_authenticated()
False
```

I've tried overriding other methods such as `get_object()`, `get_context_data()` adn others. I each of them there is `self.request` attribute available, but `user` is still `Anonymus`.

So my question is: **How on Earth am I supposed to check if user is logged in using Class-based views!?**

Does it mean I have to (go back and) use function-based views?

I'm using `Python 2.7.1+` and `Django version 1.4 pre-alpha SVN-16627`

**In response to EVIAAC post:**
Using `login_required` or `permissions_required` decorators is not an option. I need to check for permissions/logon after I retrieve object: if object has boolean field `registration_required` set to `True` only reqistered users will be able to see the page, others will get redirected to logon page (example behavior borrowed from `django.contrib.flatpages`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works properly in 1.3:

```
class TestView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

ipdb> request.user
<User: zk>
ipdb> request.user.is_authenticated()
True
```

Possibly a bug?

Comment: That must be someting else. I;ve created testproject with testapp with testmodel with testview using django 1.3 and it's still same result. Maybe there is someting I'm missing. Could you please post you full test code?

Comment: That is the full code. The only thing missing is the urlconf, which is as you'd expect: `url(r'^test', TestView.as_view())`

Comment: It appears that this bug is present only using firefox which is quite odd. :/

Comment: Checked in another 1.3 project as well, not sure what you could be doing wrong.

Comment: I also use Firefox, and don't see this behavior.

Comment: Possibly an errant add-on I suppose?

Comment: It's clean instalation of xubuntu with firefox. No idea why this is happening. While using links browser I can acces request.user.

Comment: Same behavior in chrome - anonymususer

Comment: Works fine in chrome here. And safari, for that matter.

Comment: It's a bug in django 1.4. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @seler, if zeekay's answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. Also, if you've found the problem, you should add it as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the decorators from `django.contrib.auth.decorators`. In your `urls.py`, you can do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

...
url(r'^something/?$', login_required(MyDetailView.as_view()))
...
```

For checking permissions, you can use the `premissions_required` decorator. For more info, check out the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: using `login_required` or `permissions_required` decorators is not an option. I need to check for permissions/logon after I retrieve object: if object has boolean field `registration_required` set to `True` only reqistered users will be able to see the page, others will get redirected to logon page (example behavior from `django.contrib.flatpages`).

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'd recommend writing your own views, since they seem to require more specific behavior. No sense in trying to shoehorn this behavior into generic views.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about generic views. The problem appears in class-based views, in function-based generic views it works perfectly. Since django has introduced class-based [generic] views it seems proper to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I use mixins for class based views. In this case, you can do it like this:

[Django Class-Based Generic Views and Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629426/django-class-based-generic-views-and-authentication)