# Get parameters slugs from the URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get two parameters out of the URL to add to my context.

This is the URL:

```
  url(r'^company/(?P<company>[\w\-\_]+)/?/(?P<program>[\w\-\_]+)/?$', RegistrationView.as_view(),
                       name='test'),
```

The view:

```
class RegistrationView(RegistrationMixin, BaseCreateView):
    form_class = AppUserIntroducerCreateForm
    template_name = "registration/register_introducer.html"
    slug_field = 'company'



    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistrationIntroducerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(self.get_slug_field())
        context['company'] = ??????
        context['program'] = ??????
        return context
```

I have tried everything to get the values `self.company`, `kwargs['company']` etc, what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: self.kwargs is the way to go. An example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629426/django-class-based-generic-views-and-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth) is SO reference for you .

```
context = super(RegistrationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
print(self.get_slug_field())
context['company'] = self.kwargs['company']
context['program'] = self.kwargs['program']
```

Comment: For pete sake! I tried them all. that worked thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
self.kwargs['company']
self.kwargs['program']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `as_view` class method of the base class (`View`) is a closure around a pretty simple `view` function that accepts the arguments defined in urls.py. It then assigns them as a dictionary to `self.kwargs` attribute of the view class. Therefore what you need to do in order to access this data is:

```
self.kwargs['company']
```

Also, if you inherited your `RegistrationView` from  `CreateView` instead of `BaseCreateView`, you'd get `SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` mixed in with your view and the `slug_field` (along with `model` or `queryset`) would be used by `get_object` method to fetch the desired company. Furthermore, the context variable `company` containing the `Company` instance would be already set for you and you would not have to set it yourself.