# django class based delete view and validation

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

My view:

```
class ModEmailDeleteView(DetailView):
    model = EmailModel
    template_name = "email_delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('moderator_profile', request.user.id)
```

Here I want to check if the user of particular filed is request user then only he can delete. Like

```
if obj.user == request.user
```

then only he can delete or throw 404

Also what if I have multiple primary key in the url?? and want different validations using those primary keys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Class-Based Generic Views and Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629426/django-class-based-generic-views-and-authentication)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
class ModEmailDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = EmailModel
    template_name = "email_delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('moderator_profile', request.user.id)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.object = self.get_object()
       if self.object.user == request.user:
          self.object.delete()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
       else:
          raise Http404 #or return HttpResponse('404_url')
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is mixin for django Deleview , you just override the delete
>   function in your view,

```
class DeletionMixin(object):
"""
A mixin providing the ability to delete objects
"""
success_url = None

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Calls the delete() method on the fetched object and then
    redirects to the success URL.
    """
    if self.object.user = request.user:
      self.object.delete()        
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```