# Django Guardian - How to use a permission_required decorator with a class based view?

Tags: django

I have a CB DeleteView that I am trying to decorate with Guardian's permission_required. The permission should be for the logged in user and for the object of the DeleteView. The Guardian docs aren't too clear about this, so I'm wondering if anyone could clarify.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one, check it out. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views

Answer (score 5):

I encountered almost the same problem and here is my solution (adapted to your case):

## views.py

```
class MyModelDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model=MyModel

    @method_decorator(permission_required_or_403('myapp.delete_mymodel',
        (MyModel, 'slug', 'slug'), accept_global_perms=True))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyModelDeleteView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that you can pass **accept_global_perms** parameter, that is **False** by default. It allows users with **'myapp.delete_mymodel'** permission to delete any object of **MyModel** class. This can be useful for moderators, for example.

[Guardian Decorators documentation](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.decorators.html).

Comment: Updated guardian decorators documentation link [here](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/check.html#using-decorators)

Answer (score 0):

To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the dispatch() method of the class.For xample,

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Example.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ExampleView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am aware of this. However, I am specifically asking how to include the user and the model object in the Guardian permission decorator in a CBV. Thanks!