# method_decorator login_required does not work?

Tags: django, authentication, django-class-based-views

I'm a django newbie, and I just finished the tutorial (part 04), so now I want to continue and see if I can add some authentication to my project. I want to restrict access to the polls_results page, you can only see it when you're logged in. In the last part the result pages are served by a generic view (DetailView) which I subclassed and added a method decorator to the overriden dispatch method.

```
class VoteResults(DetailView):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(VoteResults, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Following the tutorial, after submitting my vote I expect to see an `not authorized error` (401?), but I still see the results page (no error) even that I'm definitely not logged in. Is there something I'm missing? All the middleware and installed apps are present in settings.py as indicated by the docs I believe.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Probably an typo in the dispatch method name. So the decorator was never hit.

Comment: It could just be your code here but you're decorating a method named `dispatched` not `dispatch`.

Comment: Yep it's a just my code here, edited question. Double checked with a log statement which is executing.

Comment: what if you use `@login_required` instead of `@method_decorator(login_required)` ?

Comment: @Mark Lavin. After a runserver restart things have changed, it appears to be working now, not sure if the dispatched caused it, thanks for contribution.

Comment: @machaku @login_required gives also a different error `'VoteResults' object has no attribute 'user'` where method_decorator gives an error that login page is not present which is also true. That maybe another question.

Comment: @dr jerry. Probably I was wrong. I think `@login_required` is not a right way of doing things in class based views, it works on function based views.

Comment: The cleanest method I've seen is mjtamlyn's `@class_view_decorator` answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8429311/400691

Comment: This is just a guess: Maybe you had another browser window open with your user logged into your admin site? If so the login_required just recognizes an authenticated user and will not redirect to whatever login page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of decorator, use a mixin with the similar behaviour. You can write one yourself, but I strongly suggest using `LoginRequiredMixin` from [Django Braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.2/access.html#loginrequiredmixin).

Edit: To elaborate, the method decorator isn't working because you're applying it to the wrong method. You could use `login_required`, but when calling the actual view in the URLConf, like this:

```
url(r'^my_url$', login_required(MyClassView.as_view()), name='my_view')
```

However, the mixin is a cleaner and more generic approach.