# How can i put authentication on class views in django

Tags: python, django

IN the Django docs they say this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
```

But how can i use login_required on class based view

```
@login_required
classMyCreateView(CreateView):
```

This gives error

`'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746181/456550 for the current (2019) answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that in many ways like

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views

1. Either this

> ```
>  urlpatterns = patterns('',
>         (r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
>         (r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
>     )
> ```

2. Or this

> ```
> class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
>     template_name = 'secret.html'
>
>     @method_decorator(login_required)
>     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: is it posiible to add multiple decorators using urls.py?

Answer (score 3):

For Django 1.9 or greater; Class Based Views (CBVs) can utilize the `mixin` from the auth package. Simply import using the below statement -

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```

> A mixin is a special kind of multiple inheritance. There are two main situations where mixins are used:
>
> 1. You want to provide a lot of optional features for a class.
> 2. You want to use one particular feature in a lot of different classes.
>
> Learn more : [What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/433587)

---

### CBV using login_required decorator

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .views import ListSecretCodes

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^secret/$', login_required(ListSecretCodes.as_view()), name='secret'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from vanilla import ListView

class ListSecretCodes(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = SecretCode
```

---

### CBV using LoginRequiredMixin

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ListSecretCodes

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^secret/$', ListSecretCodes.as_view(), name='secret'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from vanilla import ListView

class ListSecretCodes(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = SecretCode
```

> **Note**
>
> The above example code uses [django-vanilla](http://django-vanilla-views.org/) to easily create Class Based Views (CBVs). The same can be achieved by using Django's inbuilt CBVs with some extra lines of code.