# How to write separate views for GET and POST

Tags: django

First of all I want both views use exact same URL because I don't want to make my URLConf more complicated. I want separate views for GET and POST to make my code cleaner. The code is something like this:

```
def view2 (request):
    # handle POST request, possibly a ajax one
    return HTTPRESPONSE(json_data, mimetype="Application/JSON")

def view1 (request):
    if method == POST:
        view2(request)
        # What should I return here???

    else:
        # handle GET
        return render(request, template, context)
```

My question is about the `# What should I return here???` line. If I don't put a return there, error occurs:

> not returning http response

But I already return an HTTP response in view2. How can I make this work?

Comment: You should  `return view2(request)`. View2 returned it's result to the caller (which is `view1`), but the caller needs to return it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return the results of view2:

```
def view1 (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return view2(request)
    else:
        # handle GET
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 11):

Another, probably a bit cleaner way would be using [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class View1(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """handle get request here"""

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """handle post request here"""

    def head(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """handle head request here. Yes, you can handle any kind of requests, not just get and post"""
```

Of course you can add common methods, `__init__` (which is useless unless you are sure what you are doing), apply `login_required` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views)) and pretty much everything you can do with django views (e.g. apply middleware, permissions, etc.) **and** python classes (e.g. inheritance, metaclasses/decorators, etc.)

Also, there's a whole bunch of generic class based view coming with Django to address common situations like list page, details page, edit page, etc.

Comment: I really like this answer. It makes the code very clear and easy to maintain.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to handle views. You don't want to write two large complicated logic inside `if else` when you can call separate functions.