# How To Restrict Pages or Models based on User/Group Permissions with CBVs?

Tags: python, django

***Solution thanks to Sk1p:***

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

**ip_manager/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<groupname>\w+)/tag/add/$', permission_required('ip_manager.add_tag')(TagFormView.as_view()), name='tag-add'),
)
```

---

I am trying to restrict users from adding, changing, or deleting a model. I am using only CBVs. I have looked at the following examples..

[Decorating the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

and

[How to use permission_required decorators on django class-based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views)

My problem is I want to tell which permission a user needs to access, but I am not sure how to specify it. I tried passing the permission as a arg in login-required and tested it on a user with no permissions set. This method did not work it still allowed me to add a new model object. Does any one have any suggestions?

**ip_manager/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<groupname>\w+)/tag/add/$', login_required(TagFormView.as_view(), 'ip_manager.add_tag'), name='tag-add'),
)
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify the needed permissions, you need to use [the `permission_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required). Because it takes an argument, something like the following should work:

```
permission_required("your_permission")(TagFormView.as_view())
```

This is also stated in the documentation: [Decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)

Comment: Wow if I had just read up one paragraph on Decorating class-based views I would have got that. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to restrict permissions on Class-Based Views (instead of the URL route) is to use `Groups` within the admin panel and a `PermissionRequiredMixin` on the view itself. Just apply the `PermissionRequiredMixin` as such...

```
class MemoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'memos.can_change_memo'
    model = Memo
```

... then add users to specific `Groups` within the admin panel and apply `can_change_memo` permissions to that `Group`.. Or better-yet, apply the group to the users on sign-up!