# Django Decorator Attribute Error for Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-class-based-views, attributeerror

I'm trying to use a decorator on the dispatch methods of several Class Based Views in my Django app. Here is one example view I tried:

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name="omninectar/dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ....

    @active_and_login_required
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashboardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

With the following decorator:

```
active_required = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active)

def active_and_login_required(view_func):
    decorated_view_func = login_required(active_required(view_func))
    return decorated_view_func
```

Which gets me the following error:

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/

'DashboardView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

How can I get the decorator to retrieve the current user with this view?

Comment: Can you post the whole `DashboardView`? The problem might not be in the code you posted.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the old-style decorator to a method decorator by using `django.utils.decorators.method_decorator` like this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
...

class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name="omninectar/dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ....

    @method_decorator(active_and_login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashboardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Related documentation is here: [Introduction to Class-based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew I was forgetting something simple.