# django 403 forbidden - redirect to login

Tags: django

How can I redirect a user to the login page when confronted with a 403 Forbidden?

Consider the following code:

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

        renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer, renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer)
        template_name='rest_framework/users.html'

        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            response = super(viewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
            if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
                return Response({'request':request, 'queryset': response.data['results']})
            return response
```

If I visit /domain/users while not logged in, I'll get a **403 Forbidden** error.  I would like to instead, redirect to the login page.  In other words, never show 403 errors but instead redirect directly to the login page.

I have tried putting:

```
@login_required
def list(...):
```

but that does not work.  I assume because its inside a viewset.

I have also tried:

```
def list(...):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('domain/login.html')
```

but again, doesn't work.

I tried various 403middlewares but to no avail.

I tried redirecting via the handler403 handler in urls.py

```
handler403 = 'site.views.login'
```

No success.

What to do?

Django version: 1.5.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the standard `login_required` decorator on a class method. You have to either wrap the `as_view()` when you use it in the URL:

```
url(r'...', login_required(UserViewSet.as_view()))
```

or wrap the decorator with `django.utils.decorators.method_decorator` and apply it to the class `dispatch` method:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)

For class-based views you can incorporate this into a reusable `PermissionRequiredMixin` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6455140/839875

Alternatively you can raise a `django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied` exception which Django will catch with `django.views.defaults.permission_denied`

(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view)

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you very much.

class UserViewSet(...)
@method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: There's a neat mixin which you can use for do that too, have added it to my answer