# Django "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'"

Tags: python, django

when i use user_passes_test decorators an error display :

> "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'"

this is my code :

urls.py :

```
url(r'^user/admin/$', UpdateAdminView.as_view(), name='admin'),
```

views.py :

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UpdateAdminView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "admin.html"
```

Comment: You should put method decorator. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the method decorator for your superuser check, just as you do for login required.

Since a user must be logged in to be a superuser, you can remove the `login_required` decorator in this case.

```
superuser_required = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

@method_decorator(superuser_required, name='dispatch')
class UpdateAdminView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "admin.html"
```

You may want to look at [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) as an alternative for class based views.