# How to test a method decorated with @staff_member_required in class based views?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a view like so:

```
class MyView:
    @staff_member_required 
    def post(self, request):
        #some logic
```

I'm using pytest https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for testing.

I tried this:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_upload_payments(rf):
    with open("tests/fixtures/test_payments.csv") as f:
        request = rf.post("/invoice_admin/upload_payments/",
                          {"invoice_file": f})

        resp = MyView().post(request)
        assert resp.status_code == 201
```

However, i get an error:

```
request = <WSGIRequest: POST '/invoice_admin/upload_payments/'>, args = (), kwargs = {}

    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>       if test_func(request.user):
E       AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py:20: AttributeError
```

If i remove `@staff_member_requred`, everything works fine - the test runs as expected.

How do I fix this?

I don't really care about being an admin with the right credentials for testing -- i just want to "force login" and be able to run the test.

Comment: I think you should write  `@method_decorator` like this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069444/6265279

Answer (score 3):

[According to pytest-django's doc](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#rf-requestfactory), in your case, `rf` is a django `RequestFactory` instance, so your question is "how to set the user when using RequestFactory" - [which is documented too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#example): you just have to set `request.user = some_user_object` (where `some_user_object` can be anything that satisfies the `staff_member_required` decorator's needs).

How and yes: the fact it's a class-based is actually totally irrelevant.