# Django Rest Framework Client Authentification

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, api-key

I want to setup an e-commerce store with a Django Rest Framework on the backend and React JS on the frontend and I also want to build a mobile application for the store.

I want the api to be only accessible by my React Front End client and my Mobile app, but I want my customers to see the product list without signing up or logging in first.

Is there a way to authenticate the client (the application itself) just for one view and all for all other views the user has to authenticate?

Do I need to setup an API key? Can you guys help me with some examples please?

Answer (score 1):

you can define all of your views as "required permission" by default, in the settings.py file add:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # check that token where provided and who is the user
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

in any other view that you want to be open for everyone use:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

[Django Permission Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099040/django-permission-required)